# getting a list in MVC from Umbraco

Tags: list, model-view-controller, umbraco

I have Umbraco Document types MyContent and MyContentList. MyContentList has a list view of MyContent. In the partial View I have

```
    @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<ContentModels.MyContentList>
    @using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;

    @{
        Layout = "";
    }

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/MyView.cshtml",
     new MyProject.Models.MyContentList()
     {
         Target = @Umbraco.Field("ContentTarget").ToString(),
         Items = ???
     }
```

How do I get the list of items from Umbraco and pass it in my MVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've loaded the `Umbraco.Web` namespace so the extension method can be used:

```
@using Umbraco.Web
```

Then you can try something like the following:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Content.Children<ContentModels.MyContent>()){
// do something here
}
```

Also review the documentation on our.umbraco.com here:

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Querying/IPublishedContent/Collections

Comment: I have tried but I'm getting the following error: Compiler Error Message: CS0122: 'Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent.PublishedContentWrapped.Content' is inaccessible due to its protection level on Model.Content.Children

Comment: You may need to make sure the `Umbraco.Web` namespace is loaded as `Children<T>()` is an extension method.  I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: This works only if I remove "@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<ContentModels.MyContentList>
    @using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels; "